# Access VBA to append comments to textbox (edited)

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, append

Question: If I have a textbox on an Access form with comments already in the textbox, How can I create a button to insert another comment to append without deleting the current comments? Example: Textbox with first comment. [click button] to add second comment either after the first comment or next line.
[click Button1] with first comment.

```
me.comment="first comment"
```

[click button2] that has second comment to append with first comment.

```
me.comment="with new second comment added without deleting first comment"
```

to get something like this...

```
first comment with new second comment added without deleting first comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called string concatenation, used with a `&` (or a `+`) to combine two strings.

You mean that?

```vb
Me.comment = "first comment"

Me.comment = Me.comment & " " & "with new second comment added without deleting first comment"
```

`& " "` adds a blank between the current and the appended content.

But you could also just use it like this if you add the blank to the string to be added:

```vb
Me.comment = Me.comment & " with new second comment added without deleting first comment"
```

If you want to add a new line between, you can do it like this:

```vb
Me.comment = Me.comment & vbNewLine & "with new second comment added without deleting first comment"
```